# Save specific sheet to a new workbook using vba

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I am working on a vba project. My requirement is, to delete/move a existing sheet from an excel file to a new excel file using vba code. That means to Save specific sheet to a new workbook. I have tried it alot but the file which is being saved is not a new workbook. It is the existing one.

Code is as below :

```
xlWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Copy    -- this line opens sheet3 as a new workbook

xlWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").SaveAs "***Path where file is be saved***", FileFormat:=56   -- this line save the original excel file including Sheet1 and Sheet2. But requirement is only having Sheet3.

xlWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Delete  -- this line delete the Sheet3 from original as expected.
```

I can not use any kind of reference file or Excel 12.0 Object library. So 
Please if anyone can suggest me or help me. Will appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two lines:

```
xlWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Copy
xlWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "***Path where file is be saved***", FileFormat:=56
```